# Groovy Transform Vector from soap Response

Tags: soap, vector, groovy

I'm on my first steps with groovey and soapUI:

My question is about how to transform an vector from soap response to a list and then assert values of the vecorts elements.

The response is like that

```
<![CDATA[<Vector>
  <Object>
    <pk>1</pk>
    <valueA>B</valueA>
    <valueB>20132</valueB>
  </Object>
  <Object>
    <pk>2</pk>
    <valueA>C</valueA>
    <valueB>666</valueB>
  </Object>
</Vector>]]>
```

This Vector I want to transform into an List to compare it with a lokal List, maybe something like this

```
def localCompare = new Arraylist[2]
def Objekt = new Array[3]
Objekt['pk'] = 1
Objekt['valueA'] = B
Objekt['valueB'] = 20132

localCompare.add(Objekt)

Objekt['pk'] = 2
Objekt['valueA'] = C
Objekt['valueB'] = 666

localCompare.add(Objekt)

assert localCompare.size() == 2

assert localCompare[1]['pk'] == 1
```

Note: I'll do it in a loop for each entry but I just wanted to show that I want to compare the response vector to local values

Comment: what about the docs?  http://groovy.codehaus.org/Processing+XML e.g. http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ou can use Groovy's XmlParser as well in order to deal with the response data

So, just parse you xml, firstly
To get the items of the response use such way :

```
groovy> def xml = '''<Vector> 
groovy>   <Object> 
groovy>     <pk>1</pk> 
groovy>     <valueA>B</valueA> 
groovy>     <valueB>20132</valueB> 
groovy>   </Object> 
groovy>   <Object> 
groovy>     <pk>2</pk> 
groovy>     <valueA>C</valueA> 
groovy>     <valueB>666</valueB> 
groovy>   </Object> 
groovy> </Vector>''' 
groovy> def records = new XmlParser().parseText(xml) 
groovy> println records.Object.pk[0].text() //return from <pk>1</pk> 
groovy> println records.Object.pk[1].text() //return from <pk>2</pk> 
groovy> println records.Object.valueB[0].text() //return from <valueB>20132</valueB> 
groovy> println records.Object.valueB[1].text() //return from <valueB>666</valueB> 
groovy> println records.Object.valueA[0].text() //return from <valueA>B</valueA> 
groovy> println records.Object.valueA[1].text() //return from <valueA>C</valueA> 

Output:
1
2
20132
666
B
C
```

in addtitional to, check that source look at here http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlParser

Comment: Thank you so far. I'll take a look into it later. Got lots of different stuff thrown at my desk this morning so I have to break the groovy scripting for now.

Comment: @bish, okay, if u have any questions let me know

Comment: Ok back again on my groovy scripting. Thanks for your answer, it helped me to get my things done!